# How to check and uncheck group of checkboxes using javaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have just started learning JavaScript, I am trying to solve my problem, I have those group of checkboxes, my aim is to check all checkboxes and  log checkboxes data attribute values, which works in my code, but problem is, When  I want to uncheck all of them an clear loged data, or just uncheck one of them and delete this data from `checkedItems` array, the data is added to the existing `checkedItems` array. thanks in advance

```js
var checkedItems = [];

function check() {
  var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.checkboxes');
  for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = false;
    if (checkboxes[i].type == "checkbox") {
      if (!checkboxes[i].checked) {
        checkboxes[i].checked = true;
        checkedItems.push(checkboxes[i].getAttribute('data-value'));
      } else {
        checkboxes[i].checked = false;
        checkedItems = [];
      }
    }
  }

  console.log(checkedItems)
}



function checkSingle(e) {
  checkedItems.push(e.target.getAttribute('data-value'))
  console.log(checkedItems)
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" onchange="check()">
<label for="vehicle1"> check all</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="vehicle1" class="checkboxes" onchange="checkSingle(event)" name="vehicle1" value="Bike" data-value="50">
<label for="vehicle1"> I have a bike</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="vehicle2" name="vehicle2" class="checkboxes" value="Car" onchange="checkSingle(event)" data-value="60">
<label for="vehicle2"> I have a car</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="vehicle3" class="checkboxes" name="vehicle3" onchange="checkSingle(event)" value="Boat" data-value="60">
<label for="vehicle3"> I have a boat</label><br>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var checkedItems = [];

function check(e) {
    var checkAll = e.target.checked;
    var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.checkboxes');
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        //checkboxes[i].checked = false;
        if (checkboxes[i].type == "checkbox") {
            if (!checkboxes[i].checked && checkAll) {
                checkboxes[i].checked = true;
                checkedItems.push(checkboxes[i].getAttribute('data-value'));
            } else if(!checkAll) {
                checkboxes[i].checked = false;
                checkedItems = [];
            }
        }
  }
  console.log(checkedItems)
}

function checkSingle(e) {
    var value =  e.target.getAttribute('data-value');
    if(e.target.checked==false){
        checkedItems.splice(checkedItems.indexOf(value),1);
    } else{
        checkedItems.push(value)
    }
    console.log(checkedItems)
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" onchange="check(event)">
<label for="vehicle1"> check all</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="vehicle1" class="checkboxes" onchange="checkSingle(event)" name="vehicle1" value="Bike" data-value="50">
<label for="vehicle1"> I have a bike</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="vehicle2" name="vehicle2" class="checkboxes" value="Car" onchange="checkSingle(event)" data-value="60">
<label for="vehicle2"> I have a car</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="vehicle3" class="checkboxes" name="vehicle3" onchange="checkSingle(event)" value="Boat" data-value="60">
<label for="vehicle3"> I have a boat</label><br>
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r9xjnhyc/)

Answer (score 0):

You're going over the stream to fetch water. :) Just loop through them all to check them or uncheck them.

If you want to get the data, if you want to send a form, just do a querySelector. No need to store the variables, when you can reach them with `'.checkboxes:not([id="checkAll"])'`, meaning that you exclude the `#checkAll` checkBox.

I also changed this:

```
<label for="vehicle1"> check all</label>
```

To this:

```
<label for="checkAll"> check all</label>
```

It's also better to add eventlisteners through javascript code than adding them as attributes on HTML elements.

```js
let allCheckbox = document.getElementById('checkAll');

function checkAll(isChecked) {  
  var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.checkboxes:not([id="checkAll"])');
  
  for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = isChecked;
  }
}

allCheckbox.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  checkAll(event.currentTarget.checked);
});
```

```css
label {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="checkAll">
<label for="checkAll"> check all</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="vehicle1" class="checkboxes" name="vehicle1" value="Bike" data-value="50">
<label for="vehicle1"> I have a bike</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="vehicle2" name="vehicle2" class="checkboxes" value="Car"  data-value="60">
<label for="vehicle2"> I have a car</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="vehicle3" class="checkboxes" name="vehicle3" value="Boat" data-value="60">
<label for="vehicle3"> I have a boat</label><br>
```